# How to run Mocha tests in a defined order

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

**Background**

I am working on a program in Node.js and writing my test suites in Mocha with Chai and SinonJS. I have core graphics module which controls access to a `node-webgl` context.

Due to how `node-webgl` works, I only wish to initialize a context once for the entire test run. I have some tests I wish to run prior to the initialization of the core module, like so:

```js
describe('module:core', function () {
    describe('pre-init', function () {
        describe('.isInitialized', function () {
            it('should return false if the module is not initialized', function () {
                expect(core.isInitialized()).to.be.false;
            });
        });
        describe('.getContext', function () {
            it('should error if no context is available', function () {
                expect(function () {
                    core.getContext();
                }).to.throw(/no context/i);
            });
        });
    });
    describe('.init', function () {
        it('should error on an invalid canvas', function () {
            expect(function () {
                core.init(null);
            }).to.throw(/undefined or not an object/i);
            expect(function () {
                core.init({});
            }).to.throw(/missing getcontext/i);
        });
        it('should error if the native context could not be created', function () {
            var stub = sinon.stub(global._canvas, 'getContext').returns(null);
            expect(function () {
                core.init(global._canvas);
            }).to.throw(/returned null/i);
            stub.restore();
        });
        it('should initialize the core module', function () {
            expect(function () {
                core.init(global._canvas);
            }).not.to.throw();
        });
    });
    describe('post-init', function () {
        describe('.isInitialized', function () {
            it('should return true if the module is initialized', function () {
                expect(core.isInitialized()).to.be.true;
            });
        });
        describe('.getContext', function () {
            it('should return the current WebGL context', function () {
                var gl = null;
                expect(function () {
                    gl = core.getContext();
                }).not.to.throw();
                // TODO Figure out if it's actually a WebGL context.
                expect(gl).to.exist;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Then I can run the remaining tests.

**Problem**

When I run this through Mocha, everything is fine since the core test suite is the first thing to be run. My concern is that if any test suites get run before the core test suite, then those test suites will fail as the core is not initialized yet.

What is the best way to ensure the core test suite is always run before any other test suites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I refactored my code to permit the core module to be torn down without affecting `node-webgl` and using a `before` block to initialize it, like so:

```js
// Run this before all tests to ensure node-webgl is initialized
before(function () {
    if (!global._document) {
        global._document = WebGL.document();
        global._document.setTitle('Machination Graphics Test Suite');
    }
    if (!global._canvas) {
        global._canvas = global._document.createElement('canvas', 640, 480);
    }
});

describe('test suite goes here', function () {
    // Ensure core is ready for us before testing (except when testing core)
    before(function () {
        if (!core.isInitialized()) {
            core.init(global._canvas);
        }
    });
    // Tear down core after all tests are run
    after(function () {
        core.deinit();
    });
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use before() as described in their documentation.

```
describe('hooks', function() {
    before(function() {
        // runs before all tests in this block
    });
    ......
});
```

the function in before will run first and everything else int he describe after it.

hope this helps.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. I need the test suite to run before any other test suites, not to run things before the test suite itself.

Comment: Well using one test suite to setup something for another suite is not a good pattern. You want to separate them in a different suites, but they cannot run independent from each other which defeats the purpose of them being in different suites. I would recommend going in a different direction. but if you are set on doing it this way, you can create a file called tests.js and the require("./suite1.js"), require("./suite2.js") and so on in it as describes are executed top to bottom as JavaScript itself is. Sorry for not understanding your question correctly the first time.

Comment: It's not a good pattern, I agree, but it's something I've run into due to how `node-webgl` works. I may look at refactoring my core module to see if I can add some way to tear it down after each test without running head-first into `node-webgl` restrictions. I really want to avoid having to manually import all my test suites via `require` as that's both tedious to implement and hard to maintain.